# Как обрезать Shapes по PathFigure?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-canvas

Не получается каким-либо образом обрезать Shapes элемент по контуру PathFigure. Подскажите пожалуйста, куда глубже копать.

Нашел только свойство Clip, но оно не применимо для моей задачи. На фото выделены линии, часть которых не должны отображаться. То есть это и есть постановка данного вопроса.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И конечно сам код:

```
<Path  Name="form" Fill="#FF2D7C7C" Opacity="1" Visibility="Visible" StrokeThickness="0.5" >
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry> 
                    <PathFigure x:Name="forme"  StartPoint="205, 142.5">
                        <PolyQuadraticBezierSegment x:Name="form_gg" Points="231.5, 162.5  258, 142.5,
                                                    276, 140.5 284, 147.3,
                                                    285, 190.3 260, 248.3,
                                                    269, 248.3 203, 248.3
                                                    176, 190.3 179.4, 147.3,
                                                    187.4, 140.3, 205, 142.5" >

                        </PolyQuadraticBezierSegment>
                    </PathFigure>


                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
        <Polyline Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="4"
                  Points="205, 145, 205, 255, 215, 145, 215, 255, 225, 145"></Polyline>
```

Конечно, спасибо огромное тому, кто откликнется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему же неприменимо? Прекрасно применимо.

Вот такой XAML

```
<Path Name="form" Fill="#FF2D7C7C" Opacity="1" Visibility="Visible" StrokeThickness="0.5" >
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathFigure x:Name="forme" StartPoint="205, 142.5">
                <PolyQuadraticBezierSegment x:Name="form_gg"
                                            Points="231.5, 162.5  258, 142.5,
                                                276, 140.5 284, 147.3,
                                                285, 190.3 260, 248.3,
                                                269, 248.3 203, 248.3
                                                176, 190.3 179.4, 147.3,
                                                187.4, 140.3, 205, 142.5" >
                </PolyQuadraticBezierSegment>
            </PathFigure>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
<!-- добавил для иллюстрации разницы розовую подложку -->
<Polyline Stroke="Pink" StrokeThickness="4"
          Points="205, 145, 205, 255, 215, 145, 215, 255, 225, 145"/>
<Polyline Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="4" Clip="{Binding Data, ElementName=form}"
          Points="205, 145, 205, 255, 215, 145, 215, 255, 225, 145"/>
```

производит следующий UI:

[image: результат налицо]